# I have problem with pc. Random reboots with post hyper transport sync flood error

Tags: sync, compatibility

I have problem with my pc. Random reboots with post "hyper transport sync flood" error. 
It happens completely random. Most times i watch movie, some times when i play a game, even when i browse internet.

My spec are as follow:

- MB ASUS M4A78-E
- CPU Phenom II 940
- Sapphire Radeon hd4850 Vapor-X
- RAM OCZ DDR2 PC2-8500 kit 2x2GB
- PSU CM Real Power M520W
- CASE CM Centurion 590

Temps of MB, CPU and 4850 are in normal range. MB is hooter, around 60-70°C under load, Radeon 60-65°C under load (playing game for couple hours). CPU dos not past 50-55°C. So i think its not a cooling problem, CM case is pretty good, and have a lots of fans.

I try with this memmory: TWIN2X4096-6400C5DHX same problem.

Comment: In the BIOS, have you checked the voltages supplied to the memory and to the CPU? The Corsair memory requires 1.8V, but the OCZ memory may require more depending on the specific model.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Tom's hardware](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/265878-12-hyper-transport-sync-flood-error-problem-continues)  it could be a memory voltage setting that needs to be changed from the default depending on your type of memory.  The person that was having the same problem fixed the issue by raising the voltage on the memory to 2.1 volts